# Escape backslash in math formula String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, escaping, mathjax

I use MathJax with React to display math formulas ([mathjax-react](https://github.com/charliemcvicker/mathjax-react)). I need to extract the formula code from a JSON.

I have this :

```
import React from 'react'
import { MathComponent } from 'mathjax-react'

function Card({ formula }) {
    return (
         <div>
               <MathComponent tex={String.raw`\int_0^1 x^2\ dx`} />
         </div>
    )
}
```

Instead I want to insert the formula :

```
<MathComponent tex={ formula } />
```

`formula` will be extracted from a JSON :

```
{
    "formula": `\int_0^1 x^2\ dx`
}
```

But JSON does not permit using backticks. And [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) seems to <strike>work</strike> *escape backslash correctly* only with backticks.
I would like to escape \ without modify the TeX formula (like adding a second \ manually).

How could I do?

Thanks!

*PS:
I precise that there can be multiple backslash and everywhere in the string. [Here some examples and how to create a math formula](https://atomurl.net/math/).
Using String.raw() as un function, the backslash is not extracted without the character just after. Only String.raw with backticks works well.*

Comment: `String.raw` is a tagged template string. It's a function that expects certain parameters in a certain order, and can be called like a normal function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates

Comment: Can't you use something else and replace it with backticks before rendering them?

Comment: [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) can be called like a regular function.

Comment: I tried to do String.raw(formula) but I've got an error : Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.raw (<anonymous>)

Comment: I don't understand how to use the substitutions parameter of String.raw() and apply it to my case @evolutionxbox

Comment: @sagi I would like to do without modify the TeX formula

Comment: @Splinter that's what I'm trying to figure out too

Comment: I tried `String.raw({ raw: formula})`, it worked without error but it doesn't display as before with `String.raw`\int_0^1 x^2\ dx`. The formula was broken, for example "\int" was considering as '\i' +'n' +'t', the character after the backslash was grouped with the \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS

```
const fx = {
  formula: `\int_0^1 x^2\ dx`
};

const formula = "\\" + String.raw({ raw: fx.formula });
```

in JSX

```
<MathComponent tex={formula} />
```

Codesandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/late-morning-538gf

MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw

Comment: I want to display math formulas. Your solution work only for 1 solution, the one of my example. But I have formulas where the \ are not in the beginning of the String. How could I do?

Comment: can you share some more formulas?

Comment: Example: 
\vec{F}_g=-F\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2} \vec{e}_r

Comment: You can see all possible examples and how to create a formula on this website : [https://atomurl.net/math/](https://atomurl.net/math/)